# Getting warning while importing keras with Tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just installed Keras 2.2.5 and Tensorflow 1.14 on my Windows 10 machine. I am getting some warning as follows

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0827 23:30:59.561793  9776 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

W0827 23:30:59.579783  9776 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

W0827 23:30:59.582780  9776 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.
```

Although, this warning might not hurt my program but I found it annoying. Can you please help me to reduce this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.14 is not the latest version, and most likely isn't updated anymore. That means it will have more and more dependency issues.

Comment: Please see here list of tf versions: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions